# Firefox browser Homepage setting

Tags: firefox, browser, scripting

I want to set homepages in Firefox browser.I tried to write the homepage urls in the following file
"C:\Users%username%\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\e49cn4wk.default-release\user.js".This loaded the homepage in firefox for one machine but not in the other.Why is it not getting loaded?.What should i do?Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since it's "user.js" it's clearly that the settings are local. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: i tried to write homepages in user.js of one machine.when firefox is opened it showed hompeager for say user x.For user y,i accessed user Y's user.js and wrote homepages in the file but it didn't get loaded @cdrrr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i found my answer.Firefox has two profiles for same user.So the homepages are written and loaded from the other profile.I had been looking on the wrong one